# Is "make uninstall" "make install" always needed after ./configure?

Tags: installation, configure

My question is that since options of ./configure may change from time to time. Is the following step always required?

```
make uninstall
./configure --(changed options)
make
make install
```

I also encounter errors without make uninstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the program from an installed location, then you'll want to execute that "make install" step every time you re-run configure - "make install" will likely do some post-compile configuration that you don't want to skip (such as copying updated executables from the build directory to the installation directory).

Whether or not "make uninstall" is required probably depends on exactly what you're doing. But, unless you're sure it's safe to skip that step, you should probably uninstall before the reconfiguration. For example: if one of the changed options is the install path (or the data path, etc.), skipping the "make uninstall" step would probably result in orphaned files somewhere that may be hard to clean up.

tl;dr: skipping the make install/uninstall steps *might* be safe, but I wouldn't rely on that without knowing more details.